# how to pass property value in install shield?

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012

I have created dummy MSI using wix and used APPDIR property with  one folder path for installed location .I imported this msi in to install shield and installation got success via install shield installer but I want to change the APPDIR value through install shield installer UI . Please give me the right way to proceed in install shield .How to interact with msi in installed?

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling the MSI directly from the command line it is just a matter of adding `PROPERTY=VALUE` on the command line after the install switches.

```
msiexec.exe /i setup.msi PROPERTY1="value 1" PROPERTY2=value2
```

If you're calling the InstallShield bootstrapper (setup.exe) then you'll have to wrap it in a [/v switch](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield28helplib/helplibrary/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm).

```
setup.exe /v"PROPERTY1=\"value 1\" PROPERTY2=value2"
```